# Flask Pagination - Group Unique Values Before Pagination

Tags: flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

Case: paginated page with an overview of users whom sent the 'receiver' a message. Once clicked, the receiver will go to the page with the actual conversation.

The 'overview page' is paginated (works). However, after implementation we noticed that if user X received 2 messages from Y the front-end displays two rows for Y. So we are looking for a solution to group the paginated objects - the below came to life. This however gives us the next challenge. As the pagination only retrieves the first X objects, if the next 'paginated page' contains the user from page 1 (user Y). user Y will occur on page 2 as well. I tried to create a pagination object after making the group 'unique_group' but this is just a list and cannot be paginated.

Retrieving .all() seems inefficient, especially when the application grows.

```
def group_paginated_msgs(user, Message):

    #[Y, Y, Z] = simple example 

    ''' grab user messages '''
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    
    messages = user.messages_received.order_by(
            Message.timestamp.desc()
            ).paginate(
                page, 
                5, #from config in prod.
                False
            )

    unique_authors = []
    unique_group = []

    # group user messages
    try:
        p = messages.items
        for m in p:
            if m.author in unique_authors:
                continue
            else:
                unique_authors.append(m.author)
                unique_group.append(m)
    except:
        ...

    # print(unique_group) -> [Y, Z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the .distinct() method to get the unique users from your query before you paginate?

Something like this

```
messages = Messages.query.filter(receiver==user).distinct(Message.author)
            .order_by(
                Message.timestamp.desc()
            ).paginate(
                page, 
                5, #from config in prod.
                False
            )
```

This example works by querying the messages that have been received by your user and then filtering for distinct message authors.

I'm not sure exactly what I have written will work, but I think using the distinct() method is a good place to start. You can find more info about the method [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html).